# Element not found, continue test

Tags: java, selenium

I have a page that randomly displays windows before homepage, to enter the site, I sometimes need to complete the form, so I use :

`@FindBy(xpath = "")
 public WebElement element;`

Then i try to implement solution, but it fail.

```
if(element.isDisplayed()){ 
element.click();
}else if {
do something else // if not Displayed do something else and get test true?
}
```

Get error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

In my project i use java, cucumber nad testNG. I have no idea how to do that, when it does not find a form on the page, it continues the test. Maybe I should do more methods or scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is solution:

```
@FindAll(@FindBy(xpath = ""))
    List<WebElement> buttonelements

if(!buttonelements.isEmpty()){
'code here'
}
```

**Cause of a problem:**

Using FindBy and method isDisplayed() throws NoSuchElementException if no matching elements are found.

Using FindAll and method isEmpty() don't throw any suchexception, it will return empty list.

Answer (score 0):

The error message means it cannot find the element.

Few things,

1. Do you have the right selector for that element?
2. Does the webpage use JQuery or AngularJS? If so, you need to wait for them to load
3. Are you using any type of wait? Before checking if the element exist on the page? (ex. ImplicitWait, FluentWait, Thread.sleep [bad practice])

Try this -> driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

This waits for an element to load up to 10 seconds before not finding it.

Comment: 1. This is right selector 2. Don't know 3. Yes. But it's wroks where i see this form, but sometimes i don't, like every 2-4 visits to the site. One i visit a page i see popup windows, second time i visit a page and don't see popup window

Comment: Popup windows are not consistent? What  kinda of popups are you getting?

Comment: This is the page I'm talking about [link](https://wp.pl/). This is three stage confirmation alert.

Comment: What browser are you using? I only noticed the three stage popup in edge browser and not chrome.

Comment: Try this,

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);

boolean exists = driver.findElements( By.id("...") ).size() != 0
....code to handle the pop ups

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
....proceed with rest of the test

Comment: My browser is:  Google Chrome version 65.0.3325.181 (Official) (64-bit) Your solution can be good but i want to use PageFactory

Answer (score 0):

1) You need to use something like this:
`public WebElement [] elements = driver.findElementsBy(xpath = "The Xpath you are looking for");`
`if (elements)`
In case the randomly displayed window appear your list will not be empty, will contain an element you are looking for. Otherwise the list will be empty.
Your code fails since your are looking for an element that not always existing in the page.
2) You can also use `Try` - `Catch`